# Efficiently inferring dataframe schema based on key in pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset of lines (rows) of json.  The rows have several fields and the fields that are present depend on one of the json fields in that row.  Here is an small example:

```
%pyspark
data = sc.parallelize([{'key':'k1','a':1.0,'b':2.0},
                    {'key':'k1','a':1.0,'b':20.0},
                    {'key':'k1','a':100.0,'b':.2},
                    {'key':'k2','y':10.0,'z':20.0},
                    {'key':'k2','y':1.0,'z':250.0},
                    {'key':'k1','a':1.0,'b':2.0},], 2)
```

My goal is to get this data into a Dataframe without having to specify the schema.  Pyspark has (at least) two functions to help with this: 1) `toDF()`, which just takes the first row of data as the schema and 2) `sqlContext.createDataFrame()` where you can specify the proportion of rows to sample in order to infer the schema.  e.g.:

```
data.toDF().show()
+-----+----+---+
|    a|   b|key|
+-----+----+---+
|  1.0| 2.0| k1|
|  1.0|20.0| k1|
|100.0| 0.2| k1|
| null|null| k2|
| null|null| k2|
|  1.0| 2.0| k1|
+-----+----+---+

sqlContext.createDataFrame(data,samplingRatio=1).show()
+-----+----+---+----+-----+
|    a|   b|key|   y|    z|
+-----+----+---+----+-----+
|  1.0| 2.0| k1|null| null|
|  1.0|20.0| k1|null| null|
|100.0| 0.2| k1|null| null|
| null|null| k2|10.0| 20.0|
| null|null| k2| 1.0|250.0|
|  1.0| 2.0| k1|null| null|
+-----+----+---+----+-----+
```

`sqlContext.createDataFrame()` does what I want, but since I only have maybe five keys in 4 billion rows, I am thinking that there must be a faster way to infer the schema.  Also, some keys are very rare, so I can't get away with making `samplingRatio` smaller.

Is there an elegant and fast way to have the schema inferred given there are only a few row types?

Comment: First of all using dictionaries to infer schema has been deprecated in 1.3.0 so it is really not a good option. And in general you cannot do better than a full scan if you don't want to provide schema by yourself. Just think about it - even if you check N-1 elements there is no guarantee that the N-th won't contain an additional field.

Comment: Good to know about the dictionary schema inference deprecation. Given that, what is a better approach?  

I posted an answer that used the side information about the schema being unique based on the value of the `key` key, and that seems to be the trick to making this faster.

Comment: If input is really JSON then passing data directly to JSON reader without piping from Python. Or passing the schema. It serves not only as performance booster but validation as well.

Comment: It is somewhat poorly formed json with lots of nested structure and data encoded in json keys.  Given that, Pyspark is not able to directly infer the schema from the json.  So as a preprocessing step, I flatten it into dicts in python.

Comment: If so I doubt you can do better in general especially if you have very rare keys. Basically anything you can do will be probabilistic and frequency around 10e-9 makes it rather hopeless. Still, if you pre-process this data why not infer schema at the same time? One way or another you touch all the fields, right?

Comment: Good question and that is probably the best approach.  I was trying to minimize the amount of code I have to write.  Perhaps I can dig into the schema inference function that pyspark uses and leverage those.  I'll check that out; thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more googling lead me to a solution.

Start by creating a robust dataframe concatenator (`unionAll` can't merge schema):

```
def addEmptyColumns(df, colNames):
    exprs = df.columns + ["null as " + colName for colName in colNames]
    return df.selectExpr(*exprs)


def concatTwoDfs(left, right):
    # append columns from right df to left df
    missingColumnsLeft = set(right.columns) - set(left.columns)
    left = addEmptyColumns(left, missingColumnsLeft)

    # append columns from left df to right df
    missingColumnsRight = set(left.columns) - set(right.columns)
    right = addEmptyColumns(right, missingColumnsRight)

    # let's set the same order of columns
    right = right[left.columns]

     # finally, union them
    return left.unionAll(right)


def concat(dfs):
    return reduce(concatTwoDfs, dfs)
```

(code from https://lab.getbase.com/pandarize-spark-dataframes/)

Then get the distinct keys, make a list of dataframes, and concatenate them:

```
keys = data.map(lambda x: x['key']).distinct().collect()

a_grp = [data.filter(lambda x: x['key']==k).toDF() for k in keys]

concat(a_grp).show()

+-----+----+---+----+-----+
|    a|   b|key|   y|    z|
+-----+----+---+----+-----+
|  1.0| 2.0| k1|null| null|
|  1.0|20.0| k1|null| null|
|100.0| 0.2| k1|null| null|
|  1.0| 2.0| k1|null| null|
| null|null| k2|10.0| 20.0|
| null|null| k2| 1.0|250.0|
+-----+----+---+----+-----+
```